# How to install a handheld shower without drilling the shower membrane?

Tags: drywall, waterproofing

I have a shower what had a waterproof membrane applied over it (something like Redgard) and then tiled all around.

If I drill the drywall to install a handheld shower holder I will be effectivly "destroying" the waterproof. Is there another choice for affixing it to the wall?

I have the option to install the handheld shower holder in a lateral wall that is solid brick with tile on it. It won't touch the waterproofing, but the holder will be futher from the shower (about 50-60 cm) and in an unusual layout, that I would rather avoid if possible.

Comment: It is alright to drill, just fill the holes with silicone caulk prior to inserting the fasteners. If you ever remove the unit just fill the holes up with matching color caulk. Alternatively, they do make units that require no drilling (they utilize strong waterproof adhesive); however, the choices are limited and may not offer the same features as the unit you want.

Answer (score 3):

The holes drilled for the mounting bracket of the handheld are extremely small and the bracket would further deflect water entry.

But to be especially safe, you can force a silicone sealant into the drilled holes before mounting the bracket. The screw will push it into the gap, and this will effectively heal the break in the waterproofing membrane.

If you are especially paranoid about moisture, put a dab of silicone sealant on the back of the mounting bracket itself.

Comment: +1 @bib, I must have been typing my comment while you were answering with similar advice.

Comment: I'm mostly afraid because the structure is made of steel studs (wood is not used in Brazil), so the fastener have to be anchored and I doubt it can be really sealed.

Comment: The underlying material is basically of no consequence. The silicone forms a rubbery plug and will adhere well enough to the membrane.